# Side by Side rows of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to get the data from a table, (img 1), and put on same line (img 2)

How can i do that?

It's need to be on SQL Server

i already tried select inside select, but i think that i dont know the right way to do that or if wont work with this.

```
    select * from tblTest
    where exists(select * from tblTest)
```

What i have

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDgbc.png]

What i need

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubVJA.png]

Comment: How many rows are you wanting to put as columns?

Comment: Its always 3 rows

Comment: This is not how relational data works. What happens when you have 10,000 rows? Do you expect to have 50,000 columns? This screams of being an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: sorry i didnt say that i always have 3 rows

Comment: Your table always has 3 rows? Pretty sure there are some details you are not sharing here.

Comment: hmm, its hard to explain because im trying to talk in English, but i'll try a little more.. So be patient please :)
Look, i have a lot of rows, but for the report, i need to group it by a foreign key that i have and it always 3 rows for the same fk, but i have more than 3 rows, what i trying to say its, foreach 3 rows i need to have 1 row with this all. Really sorry about my English

Comment: *"Its always 3 rows"* Yet you're sample data only has 2.

Comment: Your English seems pretty good to me. But let's avoid that language since it causes a barrier. Instead lets use the international language of data. Post some sample data and the desired output. It would be helpful to know how you know which three rows make up a "group". The query isn't that difficult once we know the scope of the problem.

Comment: This might be a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: i edit my post, better now :)

Comment: What you want is not possible because two columns in the same result set cannot have the same name.

Comment: It explains Leooso, however, your data is `text`, but you supplied it as an image; so it's not that helpful. @SeanLange gave you a good place to start, I suggest you have another look please.

Comment: thanks who tryied to help me, i'll study all of this links that you send to me and sorry for ignorance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  ID INT,
  Aux INT,
  Test1 VARCHAR(10),
  Test2 VARCHAR(10),
  Test3 VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1, 10, 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'),
(2, 11, '123', '456', '789'),
(3, 12, 'Foo', 'Bar', 'None');

SELECT T2.*,
       T1.*
FROM T T1 RIGHT JOIN T T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID +1
WHERE T2.ID % 2 > 0;
```

**Returns:**

```
+----+-----+-------+-------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | Aux | Test1 | Test2 | Test3 |  ID  | Aux  | Test1 | Test2 | Test3 |
+----+-----+-------+-------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |  10 | ABC   | DEF   | GHI   | 2    | 11   | 123   | 456   | 789   |
|  3 |  12 | Foo   | Bar   | None  | NULL | NULL | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  |
+----+-----+-------+-------+-------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7815223d69cfb8f8c00af059ec40018a)**

**Updates:**

```
INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1, 10, 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'),
(2, 11, '123', '456', '789'),
(3, 12, 'Foo', 'Bar', 'None'),
(4, 13, 'JKL', 'MNO', 'PQR'),
(5, 13, 'STU', 'VWX', 'XZ!'),
(6, 14, 'AZE', 'RTY', 'UIO');

SELECT *
FROM T T1 LEFT JOIN T T2 ON T2.ID - 1 = T1.ID
          LEFT JOIN T T3 ON T3.ID - 1 = T2.ID
WHERE T1.ID % 3 = 1;
```

**Returns:**

```
+----+-----+-------+-------+-------+----+-----+-------+-------+-------+----+-----+-------+-------+-------+
| ID | Aux | Test1 | Test2 | Test3 | ID | Aux | Test1 | Test2 | Test3 | ID | Aux | Test1 | Test2 | Test3 |
+----+-----+-------+-------+-------+----+-----+-------+-------+-------+----+-----+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |  10 | ABC   | DEF   | GHI   |  2 |  11 | 123   | 456   | 789   |  3 |  12 | Foo   | Bar   | None  |
|  4 |  13 | JKL   | MNO   | PQR   |  5 |  13 | STU   | VWX   | XZ!   |  6 |  14 | AZE   | RTY   | UIO   |
+----+-----+-------+-------+-------+----+-----+-------+-------+-------+----+-----+-------+-------+-------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=492eb77f8aadefcd045ab1089a251d67)**

Comment: its almost worked, i adapted to 3 times, but i have a column that have be always in this order: i'll show with AUX
it can be 1:8, 1:4 and 1:2 so i need to have:

ID AUX  Test1  1    1:8    abc  
ID AUX  Test1   2   1:4    123  
ID AUX  Test1  3   1:2     Foo

Comment: i didnt know that use this `% 3 = 1` its possible in sql, thanks

Comment: @Leooso Glad to help ;) and yes [it is, read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess on the OP's last comment: *"what i trying to say its, foreach 3 rows i need to have 1 row with this all."*. I suspect they therefore want this:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT {YourColumns},
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) - 1 AS RN
    FROM {YourTable})
SELECT {YourColumns}
FROM CTE C1
     LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.RN + 1 = C2.RN
     LEFT JOIN CTE C3 ON C2.RN + 1 = C3.RN
WHERE C1.RN % 3 = 0;
```

You'll need to replace the parts in the braces (`{}`) with the respective object names. Also, be warned, this is very likely to perform awfully on anything but a small dataset. The query is far from SARGable.

*Edit: In regards to the query you have in your post, it doesn't make any sense I'm afraid.*

```
select * from tblTest
where exists(select * from tblTest)
```

*This is effectively stating "return all rows and columns from the table `tblTest` if there are rows in the table `tblTest`. The `EXISTS` is therefore completely pointless, as if there are no rows in `tblTest` then the `SELECT` would return no rows anyway. Checking for the existence of rows achieves nothing but a further scan on the table.*

*It seems that you are very new to SQL, so it probably an idea to look up some tutorials and guides online first so that you can get to grip with the basics.*

Comment: i think that my query is strange too, but im trying everything to do this work and i'll try what you suggest

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have more that 2 or 3 rows in your table, you're going to need dynamic sql... The following should do the trick.

```
USE tempdb;
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN DROP TABLE dbo.TestData; END;

CREATE TABLE dbo.TestData (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    Aux INT NOT NULL,
    Test1 CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    Test2 CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    Test3 CHAR(3) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT dbo.TestData (ID, Aux, Test1, Test2, Test3) VALUES
    (1, 10, 'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'),
    (2, 11, '123', '456', '789');


-- SELECT * FROM dbo.TestData td;

--=============================================================

DECLARE 
    @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'',
    @debug BIT = 0;

SELECT TOP (2147483647)
    @sql = CONCAT(@sql, N',
    ID  = MAX(CASE WHEN td.ID = ', td.ID, N' THEN ', td.ID , N' END),
    AUX = MAX(CASE WHEN td.ID = ', td.ID, N' THEN ', td.Aux, N' END),
    Test1 = MAX(CASE WHEN td.ID = ', td.ID, N' THEN ''', td.Test1, N''' END),
    Test2 = MAX(CASE WHEN td.ID = ', td.ID, N' THEN ''', td.Test2, N''' END),
    Test3 = MAX(CASE WHEN td.ID = ', td.ID, N' THEN ''', td.Test3, N''' END)'
    )
FROM
    dbo.TestData td
ORDER BY 
    td.ID;

SET @sql = CONCAT(N'
SELECT', STUFF(@sql, 1, 1, ''), N'
FROM 
    dbo.TestData td;');

IF @debug = 1 
BEGIN
    PRINT(@sql);
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
END;
```

Results:

```
ID          AUX         Test1 Test2 Test3 ID          AUX         Test1 Test2 Test3
----------- ----------- ----- ----- ----- ----------- ----------- ----- ----- -----
1           10          ABC   DEF   GHI   2           11          123   456   789
```